# How to write a kick with reason function for my bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make my code kick people with a reason and DM them saying they have been kicked from `<server>` for the `<reason>`. At the minute it does not send a reason.

Looked at tutorials online but no luck. I have also asked some people but they did not know either. Seems not many people use discord.js, any help would be greatly appreciated. =)

[Message Bot Sends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RVof.png) [Message I Sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTXnL.png)

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');
var { prefix, logchannel } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot loaded!');
  client.user.setActivity('SUPPORT: !info', {
    type: 'PLAYING'
  });
})


client.on('message', message => {

  if (message.content === `${prefix}ping`) {
    message.channel.send('Pong.');
    console.log(`COMMAND: ${message.member.displayName} issued ping command.`);
  } else if (message.content === `${prefix}info`) {
    message.channel.send(`This server's name is: ${message.guild.name}
It has ${message.guild.memberCount} total members.
It is running **WastefulBot** by **USER HIDDEN**
For support please join LINK HIDDEN`);
    console.log(`COMMAND: ${message.member.displayName} issued info command.`);
  } else if (message.content === `${prefix}help`) {
    console.log(`COMMAND: ${message.member.displayName} issued help command.`);
    message.delete();
    message.channel.send('Please check your dm\'s.');
    message.member.send(`__**WastefulBot Help**__
!ping | Pong.
!info | Returns information on the server and how to get support for the bot.
!donate | Get information on how to donate.
!help | Shows this information.
__**Administration Commands**__
(Please note these commands require corresponding permissions)
!kick <@user> | Kicks the specified user.
!ban <@user> | Bans the specified user.
__**Management Commands**__
(Please note these commands require corresponding permissions)
!staff | Grants a user staff. (WIP - May not work on most servers.)
`);
  }

  if (message.content === (`${prefix}setlog`)) {
    if (message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNEL")) {
      message.channel.send('Sorry. This command is currently WIP.');
      console.log(`WARNING: ${message.member.displayName} issued setlog command, this command is WIP and does not work.`);
    }
  }

  if (message.content === (`${prefix}donate`)) {
    message.channel.send('You can donate at ``https://www.patreon.com/wasteful_development``');
  }

  //KICK COMMAND STARTS HERE
  else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}kick`)) {

    if (message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
      if (!message.mentions.users.size) {
        return message.reply('You must tag 1 user.');
      } else {
        let member = message.mentions.members.first();
        let reason = message.content.split(" ").slice(22);
        if (member.kickable == false) {
          message.channel.send("That user cannot be kicked!");
          return;
        } else {
          member.send(`You have been kicked from \`\`${message.guild.name}\`\` for the reason ${reason}.`).then((message) => {
            member.kick(reason).then((member) => {
              message.channel.send(" " + member.displayName + " has been kicked!");
              console.log(`KICK: ${message.member.displayName} successfully executed kick command.`);
            });
          });
        }
      }
    } else {
      message.channel.send("You do not have permission to use kick.");
      return;
    }
  }

  //End of kick mthd
  else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}staff`)) {
    if (message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) {
      if (!message.mentions.users.size) {
        return message.reply('You must tag 1 user.');
      } else {
        let member = message.mentions.members.first();
        member.addRole("569174153337503804");
        message.channel.send(`Granted ${member.displayName} staff!`);
        message.channel.send(`Warning this command will not have worked on most servers as it is WIP.`);
        console.log(`STAFF: ${message.member.displayName} successfully granted ${member.displayName} staff .`);
      }

    } else {
      message.channel.send("**You do not have permission to grant users staff.**");
      return;
    }
  }

});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: Are any errors thrown?

Comment: My errors: https://pastebin.com/NYwdhV8X

(I can't paste here as too long)
@slothiful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explanation:

Looking at your errors, this is the timeline of issues.

1. The source of all this is that the bot can't send a DM to the member due to the their **privacy settings** within the guild ([here](https://puu.sh/DikMp/c1b3163126.png)). This results in `member.send(...)` being rejected.
2. Since this rejected promise isn't caught, the code continues with `.then()` returning nothing instead of the expected `message` parameter.
3. When you try to read the `displayName` property of `message.member`, it throws an error because your parameter `message` was never returned.

#### Solution:

Implement a `.catch()` method to **handle the possibility of the rejected promise**.

Remember, you must declare your function as async to use `await`:

```js
client.on('message', async message => { // ES6
```

Then, in your command:

```js
await member.send(`You have been kicked from \`${message.guild.name}\`. Reason: \`${reason}\``)
  .catch(err => message.channel.send(`⚠ Unable to alert ${member} of reason.`));

await member.kick(reason);
await message.channel.send(` ${member} has been kicked!`);

console.log(`${message.author.tag} kicked ${member.user.tag} from '${message.guild.name}'.`);
```

Comment: It's also worthy to note that you should add a character limit to the reason to ensure the reason message doesn't exceed 2,000 characters.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked. However when the reason contains more than 1 word this happens https://imgur.com/a/vwKuQkf (My code is https://pastebin.com/bJjn9MQe) Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: When you declare `reason`, you should add `.join(' ')` to the end.

Comment: Nice Answer, btw @WastefulGlint if you want to setup a nice command structure have a look at: https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#individual-command-files

Answer (score 1):

Your bot might not be able to DM users after they have been kicked due to their privacy settings. Because the user got kicked, they no longer share a server with the bot (unless it is a very globally used bot, which would increase the odds that the user is in multiple servers using the bot,) meaning that the likelihood that the bot is not able to send a DM to that user, is very high.

Comment: He actually uses `member.send('msg').then((message) => {
            member.kick(reason)..})` so it sends the message and then kicks, but you are still right, Users can block the Bot/ have their settings on allow dms from friends only, and so the bot cant send the dm

Comment: The I was testing it on my alt (an unclaimed account on an incognito tab) and messages could be sent between the user an the bot. @PLASMA

Answer (score 0):

Your reason code should be:

```
const reason = message.content.split(' ').splice(2)
```

the number 3 represents the word in your command that the reason starts on.
e.g. >kick @ reason

so `>kick` is going to be `0`, then `@<user>` is going to be `1` and `reason` is going to be `2`, so basically splice is what word it stops on, every word after 2 is going to be your reason, including 2 if that makes sense.

I tried my best to explain it :)

Answer (score -2):

### below is not the answer, user and member both have .send()

The error in your code is `member.send()`. You see, [`member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) and [`user`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) are two different things.
`.send()` only works with a [`user`, so you should do `member.user.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=send), and it will work.
Also, you will need a catch for that promise, so if that user has DM's disabled, as the bot cannot DM the user if they have it disabled. Something like:

```
await member.user.send(`You have been kicked!`)
  .catch(() => message.channel.send("User seems to have DMs disabled!"));
await member.kick("reason")
  .then(member => message.channel.send(`${member.displayName} has been kicked!`))
  .catch(e => console.error(e.stack));
```

Keep in mind, `await` is [another way](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/async-await.html#execution-with-discord-js-code) of chaining `then` in async functions.

Comment: This is not true: [GuildMember#send](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=send)

Comment: This code does not work. It is missing 2 close brackets, I tried to add these but it gave the following error

https://pastebin.com/bEPG3ji4

(Pastebin as too long to post here)

Comment: You need to put this code in an async function. Change `client.on('message', message => {` to `client.on("message", async message => {`, make sure async is before message.

Comment: Hm still didn't seem to work. Here is the pastebin of the errors https://pastebin.com/rKjQ60pU and here is my code https://pastebin.com/Fy6wznag

Thanks. =)

Comment: Hello there, [I made it so it works](https://pastebin.com/az5P3DAn). For me, this new code works.